# Is it okay to run another query while fetching rows?

Tags: go

Instead of collecting resulting rows into slice and doing SQL query while
iterating through those rows for the second time, I think it will be better to
execute the query while calling `rows.Next()`.

Instead of this:

```golang
// error does not happen
func attempt1() {
    db, _ := sql.Open(driver, dsn)
    tx, _ := db.Begin()
    rows, _ := tx.Query(query)
    results := collectIntoSlice(rows)
    for _, row := range results {
        doOtherQuery(tx)
    }
}
```

I want this:

```golang
// error does not happen
func attempt2() {
    db, _ := sql.Open(driver, dsn)
    tx, _ := db.Begin()
    rows, _ := tx.Query(query)
    for rows.Next() {
        doOtherQuery(tx)
    }
}
```

But, is the second approach safe?

Comment: Yes. Any data-source library should support concurrent access. Just ensure you clean up any resources associated with each concurrent query e.g. `rows.Close()`.

Comment: That question lacks context in which you are planning to run that code. Does this code modifies data in DB? Is there another processes that would try to modify same data? Is that "other query" locking?

Comment: Yes, it modifies data in DB.

Comment: @MasBagol What about other 2 points? If that's only script that modifies that data and it doesn't locks it -- then long running transaction should fine. Otherwise, i would avoid it.

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin the main query is a `SELECT`. the query inside iteration is an `UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT`. For the sake of this question, let's assume that no other process accessing database other than this process (If what you mean by process is a another program) and no other goroutine accessing that database. The transaction `tx` should live to the end of iteration.

Comment: @MasBagol I see. Then long transction should be fine. But still, i would recommend to avoid it. Especially if this is not one-man project. Because it's possible, that in future someone will one to update same rows elsewhere.